# MQ service process pointing to uninstalled instances

Tags: ibm-mq

We recently migrated our v8 mq to v9.1 on same server, after migrating we uninstalled the v8 packages. We realized after uninstalling that there are still '/opt/mqm/samp/bin/amqsclm' processes running that point to the uninstalled version directory (v9.1 was installed in a separate dir). I did update the services pertaining to those process to v9.1 installation directory but not sure how to restart those process without restarting the queue manager because the planned downtime window is a couple of weeks away.
I do not have much experience with mq service.
If I let those zombie processes keep running for a couple of weeks how will it impact my MQ service?
If I just kill those processes and start them immediately will it disturb any queue/qm activity?

Comment: Try `DIS CONN(*) TYPE(ALL) WHERE(APPLTAG EQ 'amqsclm') ALL`, this will show if any processes with that name connected to the queue manager.   You can match these by PID to the processes running.   If none of them are connected just kill them.   If you have them starting via a `SERVICE` then make sure you update the path and start the service.

Comment: All those process seem to be connected. I was able to match all the PIDs to processes I was talking about. Not a good idea to kill? Whats the impact if I let them run for a couple of weeks until we get the downtime?

Comment: It should be fine, but as @Attila mentioned there would be no impact in restarting them.

Comment: Thanks Josh, was able to kill and restart.

Answer (score 0):

The amqsclm program is not part of the queue manager. So it is safe to stop/restart it, that will not stop your queue manager.

It is a sample program for monitoring cluster queues and changing cluster workload balancing depending on whether the queue is opened or not:
[Documentation of amqsclm](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q024620_.htm)

Comment: thanks for forwarding me the link. I was able to kill the processes and restart them without an incident.
Thanks for your time.